# Wait for a processing to end before saving it to the database [Solve]

Tags: javascript, express, es6-promise

I use express JS and Node JS to build a REST API

I would like to build a json object with cheerio which I would then add to my mongoDB database.

A promise is a practical solution according to, but I'm still having trouble creating promises in JavaScript.

**I made this test code**

I created a controller with this function which will analyze a url with cherrio.

the url parameter is transmitted from a post route from my API

```
exports.scrapeData = (url) => {
   console.log('Scraping data', url);
   return url;
}
```

This function of another controller retrieves the data and saves it in the database.

```
const Post = require('../models/Post');
const exportDataCtrl = require('./exportData');

exports.createDataWithUrl = (req, res, next) => {
  let url = req.params.url;

  const dataScrape = exportDataCtrl.scrapeData(url);

  const post = new Post({
    ...dataScrape
  })

  post.save()
    .then(post => res.status(201).json({ message:'success !'}))
    .catch(error => res.status(400).json({ error:error })) 
}
```

**EDIT:** Adding Post.js code, Post is a mongoDB database model that I made to perform my tests.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type:String, required:true },
  description: { type:String, required:true },
  contact_name: { type:String, required:true }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);
```

I tried to create a promise with the **scrape** Data function and the function save of mongoDB but I still get that the function then returns an undefined result.

I think I don't quite understand the promises and the error must be obvious.

Thank you in advance for your help and your answers.

Comment: Please share the code for `Post.js` where save function is implemented.

Comment: I updated my post, I also fix a syntax error

Answer (score 1):

It would appear scrapeData is a promise function, given that it will need some time to process the data from a url. In that case, the function should be *then*-able and assuming it would return the data once the function is resolved, you can derive the actual code from this:

```js
exports.createDataWithUrl = (req, res, next) => {
  let url = req.params.url;

  // assuming scrapeData returns a promise
  exportDataCtrl.scrapeData(url).then((data) => {
    const post = new Post({ data });

    post
      .save()
      .then((post) => res.status(201).json({ message: "success !" }))
      .catch((error) => res.status(400).json({ error: error }));
  });
};
```

EDIT: Here's how the scrapeData function would look like as a promise (cheerio was added in as per comment)

```
// assumes you have fetch & cheerio
function scrapeData(url) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    fetch(url)
      .then((res) => res.text())
      .then((body) => {
        const $ = cheerio.load(body);

        // do scrape here, example gets title
        const data = $("title").text();
        resolve(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => reject(error));
  });
}
```

Comment: Yes, I think given that, the cherrio scripts could take some time, so I wanted to do the scraping and then wait to recover the data.

But how could the promise be added to the scrapData function?

Comment: I have updated the sample code with cheerio particularly, feel free to derive from it and maybe give promises a read as well. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise